# How to pass environment variables to test cases in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, environment-variables

When writing test cases for Go, what is the standard way to pass in environment variables that need to be provided to the tests.

For example, we don't want to embed passwords in the source code of the test cases.

What is the most standard way to handle this? Do we have the test cases look for a config file? Something else?

Comment: I don't feel like this warrants a full answer but I think configuration files are a good way. You don't need to worry about name clashes in your environment and it's simple to see it all in one place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears I have stumbled across the answer. Adding this to test cases allows you to pass parameters, i.e.

```
var password string

func init() {
        flag.StringVar(&password, "password", "", "Database Password")
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
go test github.com/user/project -password=123345
```

(As noted below, Don't do this on a test where you don't trust other users on the test server who have access to view running processes, (i.e. perhaps your test database has sensitive data in it. However. If you are in a organisation that likes to keep sensitive data in a test environment this is probably the least of your security problems)

Comment: @lofcek This is a great caution. Although one could argue, if someone has access to the machine you are running test cases, they probably have access to your source code, and might even have access to the text file if you are storing the password in a text file. Generally it would be a good idea to ensure there is nothing secret or sensitive on your servers you are doing test cases, and the test servers should not have access to commit source code. That way if it is compromised, they don't get anything useful at all.

Comment: I don't think so. In university was normal, that every student had account on the same machine. But of course no other student has access to the school-mate’s files. And also another small reason to not to pass sensitive data through command line - the data are also stored into unexpected storage - in the file .bash_history.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the call to `flag.Parse`; you should not do that within a testing `init()` function as the test infrastructure does flag parsing.

Comment: but add the `flag.Parse()` in the main function, otherwise the arg `&password` will remain default.

Comment: The comment by @PennyQian is very important. One may improve this answer by performing the flag parsing in the TestMain function:

`func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
 flag.StringVar(&password, "password", "", "Database password")
 flag.Parse()
 if password == "" {
  usage()
  log.Fatal("Please set the database password")
 }
 retCode := m.Run()
 os.Exit(retCode)
}`

Comment: @PennyQian `flag.Parse()` is not needed in `init()` or `TestMain()` because like @DaveC said, **Command line flags are always parsed by the time test or benchmark functions run**, unless init() or **TestMain depends on command-line flags, including those of the testing package, it should call flag.Parse explicitly.** (the highlight part is from golang testing doc https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main)

Answer (score 11):

Use an env var

```
func func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
  x := os.Getenv("MY_X")
  fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Then call your test like this

```
MY_X=bar go test -v ./... -run TestFoo
```

and it should print `bar`

Comment: This is the better answer for cases where there are no security concerns.